# WinRar exit code different behavior in SP2/SP3 and 7

Tags: windows, programming-languages, winrar

I am new to windows programming and have written a small utility with mingw which will unrar a package. The code is as provided below

**Descrition:**

When the below program is run, the results are as follows

**XPSP2 32 bit and Windows 7**

- Untar Operation : Success
- CreateProcess return code : Non Zero (Success)
- exit Code : 0 (Success)

**XP2SP3 32 bit**

- Untar Operation : Success
- CreateProcess return code : Non Zero (Success)
- **exit Code : 3221225477**

---

**Problem Statement**

I am not sure why in XP2SP3 patch only, the winRar operation provides the exit code as Huge positive value. Do you find any problem in the below code? Please help in this regard.

---

```
int main()
{
    string ProgramName = "C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe";   
    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;

        memset(&StartupInfo, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    memset(&ProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION)

    if (CreateProcess((LPCTSTR)ProgramName.c_str(),(LPCTSTR)"WinRAR.exe x -y -ibck d:\\abc.tar d:\\"),NULL,
    NULL,
    FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &StartupInfo,
    &ProcessInfo) == 0)
    {
        string tmpStr("Error executing");
        tmpStr += ProgramName;
        cout<<"StmtDesigner"<<tmpStr<<"CreateProcess failed"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        string tmpStr("Succes executing");
        tmpStr += ProgramName;
        cout<<"StmtDesigner"<<tmpStr<<"CreateProcess Success"<<endl;



            WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
            DWORD exitCode=0;
            if (GetExitCodeProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, &exitCode))
            {
            string tmpStr("GetExitCodeProcess");
            tmpStr += ProgramName;
            cout<<tmpStr<<"WinRAR.exe x -y -ibc<<endl;
            }
    }

    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

---

PS : WinRar 3.8 version trail Mode is used for above testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That huge positive number, in hexadecimal, is 0xC0000005. It's a common Windows error, which means "Access Violation". Why exactly are you getting it really depends on what winrar is trying to do, but the problem might be with access rights to files. I suggest you give it a try with [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) watching your program's file activity. If accessing one of the files is denied, you'll see it in the log.

Comment: 0xC0000005 is thrown on memory read/write/execute without sufficient memory access rights. This has absolutely nothing to do with access rights on files or handles or whatever. Windows doesn't throw exceptions when you don't have enough rights to access a resource, it would set the last error to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and return false.

Comment: @pezcode, like it or not, that's the exit code the OP is getting... Why is winrar returning that value I really don't know. I can only assume winrar is using this code to signal an accessibility problem. It's obviously not the direct result of winrar using a bad pointer or so, but it might be returning that last error if a critical operation failed. Without having access to winrar's source code, we can only guess what would be the reason for returning that code.

Comment: what makes you think it's "obviously not the direct result of [...] a bad pointer"? What enterprise program returns a Windows defined exception (!= error) code on process exit? You would expect less speculation from people answering the questions here... If you still don't believe me, look at the WinRAR manual: http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/ (command line mode > exit codes)

Comment: @pezcode, I agree the use of the "obviously" was wrong here, but when processes crash, they _usually_ don't go down silently. But given the list of error codes, it does make it more possible. Anyway, speculation is the only option given winrar is a closed commercial product, and given I don't work for winrar. I'm honestly trying to help the guy. If you have some concrete information, you're more than welcome to write an answer.

Comment: @eran, Thanks for your direction. Actually you were correct - WinRar was throwing exception as exit code (which Even I am perplexed - since it is not part list of exit code mentioned).  Finally the root cause was - when thread exit happens, WinRar interacts with ntdll.dll library. One of the proprietary library was unfortunately installed at $WINDOWS/system32 location - which "somehow" interacted with the ntdll.dll and resulted in exception. Still - Not sure why the proprietary library caused the problem. Anyways - Thanks for help.